# Satisfiablity checking in non-linear integer arithmetic by approximation

Tags: z3

Is it possible to ask Z3 to prove satisfiability of a system of integer polynomial inequalities with 2 different variables (or in general case) by approximating the original system with a system of linear inequalities?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Z3 will try to solve a nonlinear integer problem as a linear one. The basic trick is to treat nonlinear terms such as `x*y` as new "variables". Nonlinear integer arithmetic is not well supported in Z3, the following post has a summary on how Z3 handles nonlinear integer arithmetic:

- [How does Z3 handle non-linear integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898175/how-does-z3-handle-non-linear-integer-arithmetic)