# Z3 support for nonlinear arithmetic

Tags: z3

I understand that Z3 has some supports for nonlinear arith but wondering to what extends ?   Is it possible to specify what classes of nonlinear arithmetics are supported and are not (or likely to give time out) ? Know these in advances will help me abort my task early.

Seems like power related stuff is not supported as shown below

```
def pow2(x): 
    k=Int('k')
    return Exists(k, And(k>=0,2**k==x))


prove(pow2(7))
failed to prove
```

Answer (score 5):

Z3 supports nonlinear *polynomial* Real arithmetic. So, there is no support for transcendental functions (e.g., sine and cosine), and exponential (e.g., `2^x`). Actually, for the exponential, Z3 can handle exponents that can be simplified to numerals. Here is an [example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/woms),

```
x = Real('x')
y = Real('y')
solve(y == 3, x**y == 2)
```

In this example, the `y` in `x**y` is rewritten to `3` during a preprocessing step. After preprocessing, the [nlsat](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/IJCAR2012.pdf) solver for nonlinear polynomial real arithmetic is invoked. 
Regarding nonlinear integer arithmetic, see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898175/how-does-z3-handle-non-linear-integer-arithmetic/13898524#13898524).