# z3 existential theory of the reals

Tags: z3

Does Z3 decide the existential fragment of nonlinear real arithmetic?
That is, can I use it as a decision procedure for testing whether a
quantifier-free formula with + and x has a solution over the reals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Z3 has a decision procedure for the existential fragment of nonlinear polynomial real arithmetic. Of course, the procedure is complete modulo available resources. The procedure is quite expensive. [This article](http://leodemoura.github.io/files/IJCAR2012.pdf) describes the procedure implemented in Z3.

Here is a small example (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/2Qap)):

```
(declare-const a Real)
(declare-const b Real)
(assert (= (^ a 5) (+ a 1)))
(assert (= (^ b 3) (+ (^ a 2) 1)))
(check-sat)
(get-model) 
(set-option :pp-decimal true) ;; force Z3 to display the result in decimal notation
(get-model)
```

Here is a related question:

- [Z3 support for nonlinear arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064822/z3-supports-for-nonlinear-arithmetics)