# exponent constraint is unknown in Z3 C API?

Tags: model, z3, exponent

I want to get the solution from Z3 C API for the constraint followed:

```
   2^x < a < 2^(x+1)
```

expression for 2^x is :

```
    t_x=Z3_mk_power(ctx,two,x), two is the expression of "2";

    2^(x+1) is similar,
```

"a" is a int const ,which value is 10:

```
   a=Z3_mk_int(ctx,10);
```

the constraints are:

```
   c1=Z3_mk_lt(ctx,t_x,a);

   c2=Z3_mk_lt(ctx,a,t_x_plus_one);
```

then I get the model is "unknown", Z3 C API cannot get a model like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description it's not clear which solving method Z3 employs in the end, but in general non-linear integer arithmetic is undecidable and Z3 can only handle simple cases of exponentials. See also Leo's answers to similar questions:

[How does Z3 handle non-linear integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898175/how-does-z3-handle-non-linear-integer-arithmetic/13898524#13898524)

[Z3 supports for nonlinear arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064822/z3-supports-for-nonlinear-arithmetics)

Comment: I wrote the constraint wrong the last time, and I edited again , this one is clear. I read Leo's answer first. thanks.