# How to write 2 power n i.e. 2^n in Z3?

Tags: z3

I am using this link to compile and see the result (http://rise4fun.com/Z3)

I just want to write 2^n say 2^100 in Z3.

Please help me how to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so: `(^ 2 n)`, see [example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/QzY0).

Note that Z3 will often give up on non-linear arithmetic (as is the case in the example). See also: [How does Z3 handle non-linear integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898175/how-does-z3-handle-non-linear-integer-arithmetic/13898524#13898524) and [Z3 support for nonlinear arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064822/z3-supports-for-nonlinear-arithmetics).