# optimization of non-linear objective functions using Z3

Tags: optimization, z3, smt

I have two equations, one of them is linear while the second one is non-linear.
I have to minimize the first one while maximizing the second one at the same time.

Is this achievable with Z3? it seems that it can't optimize non-linear equations. it returns "Unknown" with non-linear equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 optimization is mostly for the linear fragment, see this paper: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-nuz.pdf (Note that the tool described in this paper is now part of z3, yo do not need a separate executable.)

Having said that, a common trick is to use the optimizer to do the linear part; and do repeated calls to get "better" values for the non-linear parts. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49180970/936310

Comment: I tried the trick but i noticed that it generates the maximum value first. Is that a coincidence? Or is z3 designed to try greater values first?