# Modular arithmetic using z3

Tags: integer, z3, modulo, smt

I'm trying to prove statements such as the following:

```
(assert (=
    (mod i n)
    (mod j n)))

(assert (> n 0))
    
(assert (not (=
    (mod (+ i 1) n)
    (mod (+ j 1) n))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Others are:

- `(((i % n) + j) % n) == ((i + j) % n)`
- `((i - n + 1) % n) == ((i + 1) % n)`
- `((((a - 1) % n) + 1) % n) == (a % n)`

But z3 does not seem to terminate when proving these statements. Are they beyond the power of z3/smt solvers?

If it is the only way I would not mind doing more explicit proof steps, but these rules seem so elementary I would not know where to begin. Even when using induction I quickly run into cases (like the initial example) that I would expect to be true, but which do not seem to be provable with z3.

I am using z3 4.8.6, for what it's worth. Can anyone shed some light on this why this is hard, or maybe point me in the direction of papers/z3 flags that make this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer short, yes. These sorts of properties are too difficult for SMT solvers to handle. They essentially involve non-linear integer arithmetic, for which there is no decision procedure. The solver has a bunch of built-in heuristics that may or may not answer your query; but more often then not it'll go into an infinite loop as you no doubt observed.

See this answer for details:
[How does Z3 handle non-linear integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898175/how-does-z3-handle-non-linear-integer-arithmetic/13898524#13898524)

### What you can do

If you want to stick to a pure push-button solution, there isn't really much you can do. In certain cases, the following line helps:

```
(check-sat-using (and-then qfnra-nlsat smt))
```

This uses the theory of reals to solve your query (NRA: non-linear real arithmetic-which happens to be decidable), and then sees if the solution is actually integer. Obviously, that does not always work. In particular, any operation like `mod` will be difficult to deal with using this strategy.

In practice, I recommend proving specific instances of your property instead. That is, run a bunch of cases, fixing `n` each time:

```
(assert (= n 10))
```

then

```
(assert (= n 27))
```

etc. Obviously, this will not prove it for *all* `n`, but in a practical system if you pick your values of `n` carefully, you can weed out a lot of non-theorems this way.

If you really want to prove this for all `n`, then use a theorem prover instead. Obviously that won't be push-button, but that's the state of the art. There are many choices here: Isabelle, HOL, HOL-Light, ACL2, Coq, Lean, .. to name a few. Note that most of these theorem provers have built in tactics that utilize SMT solvers under the hood to discharge many of the sub-goals. So, you kind of have the best of both worlds, though of course the proof itself requires manual decomposition in such systems.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. If I would want to introduce the rules I am trying to prove as axioms in z3 (assuming it helps), do you think there is a clear way for me to proceed? For example, I could introduce the rules I am trying to prove as background axioms (i.e. as "asserts" early on in the file), and prove them manually in e.g. Lean, but then the proof obligation must be managed by me. It would be nice if Lean (or some other tool) could output the proof to disk, and then z3 can load it and check it (in an ideal world). Are you aware of such tools/approaches/extensions to z3?

Comment: This sort of communication between solvers is known as "Proof exchange" and is a current research topic. See https://pxtp.gitlab.io/2021/ for their conference; earlier proceedings might've pointers to tools. I'm not aware of anything that can be used out-of-the box though, though I'm not too familiar with the area.

Comment: As far as importing proofs to z3 is concerned: The issue is that most of these theorems are quantified (after all, that's what makes them interesting), and SMT solvers don't deal with quantification all that well. You can use quantifiers together with patterns, but support is rather finicky. See https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-e-matching-based-quantifier-instantiation

Comment: One more question: could I implement a tactic in z3 that does the simplifications I have in mind? For example, `i % n % n == i % n`? Or am I then risking introducing unsoundness? I'm talking about mostly syntactical simplifications then, of course. Since my proofs only need very basic rules like the former to pass, I think.

Comment: Sure; but writing custom tactics is not a well-documented process; nor it is straightforward. You'll have to get intimately familiar with the z3 source-base. Start by asking here for some advice: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions