# z3 quantifiers elimination in SMTLIB syntax

Tags: z3, z3py, quantifiers

I have the following example of quantifiers elimination using z3py below. However I would like to rewrite it using SMTLIB syntax (code below python code). Somehow I did not get the same output like what I got from python which are formulas. I wonder if anyone could point me out the problem.

`from z3 import *
    a, five = Ints('a five')
    cmp = Bool('cmp')

    j = Goal()
    j.add(Exists([five, cmp],   And(five == a,
                                cmp == (five < 1000), 
                                False == cmp)))

    t = Tactic('qe')
    print(t(j))    # output [[1000 <= a]]`

`(declare-fun five () Int)
    (declare-fun a () Int)
    (declare-fun cmp () Bool)
    (assert (exists ((five Int) (cmp Bool)) (and (= five a) 
                                        (= cmp (< five 1000))
                                        (= cmp false)  )))
    (apply (then qe smt))`

output 
(goals
(goal
  :precision precise :depth 1)
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the question too quickly. After more searching ([Quantifier Elimination - More questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436726/quantifier-elimination-more-questions)), I found a solution below.

`(declare-fun five () Int)
    (declare-fun a () Int)
    (declare-fun cmp () Bool)
    (assert (exists ((five Int) (cmp Bool)) (and (= five a) 
                                            (= cmp (< five 1000))
                                            (= cmp false)  )))
    (apply (using-params qe :qe-nonlinear true))`